# Delete relationship between objects with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 2 Java Classes, one called `Definition` and one calles `Classification`.
A definition has a list of classifications so `0..n` cardinality.

Here is what my object-relational mapping looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.myPackage.Definition" table="definition">
        <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>        

        <!-- definition will have many to many asscoiations with Classes -->    
        <set name="classes" table="class_definition" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="definition_id" />          
            <many-to-many column="class_id" class="com.myPackage.Classification" foreign-key="fk_class_definition" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What I am trying to do now is delete the relationship between the definition and a classification. For example definition X has classification A, B and C and I want to remove the link to classiciation C.

I know how to write a delete query in HQL to delete an object of a class. But I don't know how to delete a value of an attribute of my class.

Can anyone advice?

Comment: You said that it's a 0..n relation, meaning `@OneToMany`, but  you have `many-to-many` in mapping file, which one is correct? Is it bidirectional or unidirectional relation?

Comment: I thought the same too, but it might be just a weird hibernate mapping?

Comment: No, not hibernate fault, the correct mapping is `<one-to-many column="class_id" class="com.myPackage.Classification" foreign-key="fk_class_definition" />`

Comment: Yes it is bidirectional. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

From the question above, I see a problem in the Data-Modeling of the solution.
As per the above design, a Definition Object can contain multiple Classification Objects. And, since there is a many-to-many relationship between the two entities, a single Classification Object may associate to multiple Definition Objects.

From the question above, I realize that the Classification Object will not be a transactional entity, but more or less a System-of-Record, which means any changes to it will after all the mappings. Having said that, as per question, attempting to update an attribute of the Classification class to dis-associate the mapping can be problematic! Instead, I propose the below data model.

Current Model:
[image]

Proposed Model:
[image]

As per the proposed model, you will not be required to update any attribute of the System-of-record Classification Objects. Instead, your job will be more about deleting & creating new ClassificationMapper Objects. A sample class for Classification will look something as below:

```
class ClassificationMapper{
     Long definitionId; // Primary key for Definition
     Long classificationId; // Primary key for Classification
}
```

ClassificationMapper class will have a Many-to-1 composition relation with the Definition class and Many-to-1 association relation with the Classification class.

Comment: Changing the application itself is not really an option for me. Looking at the answers I've gotten so far it seems it cannot be done the way I had in mind. I am rewarding you the bounty  cause it is the best workaround that has been proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done using `update` query, not `delete`, because you are updating Classification instead of deleting it. Try something like this

```
update Classification c set c.definition = null where c.definition.id = :defId
```

**EDIT**

This is under assumption that the relation between `Definition` and `Classification` is bidirectional `@OneToMany`, as you said in your question, and not `many-to-many` as your mapping file says.

Comment: I think his mapping is with a join table, so this would not work, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is many-to-many so this indeed won't work, you are right, I didn't read the question carefully enough. I'll delete it, or edit if I think of another solution.

Comment: @PredragMaric Yes it is bidirectional , sorry for my late reply

Comment: @Hazaart Ok, does my suggestion work? You would first need to fix the mapping in the xml file from `many-to-many` to `one-to-many`.

Comment: @PredragMaric, The application was not written by me but I don't think I can just change the relationship. A definition can have multiple classifications and a classification can be linked to multiple definitions. So It should stay many-to-many , no?

Comment: @Hazaart Yes, but in the question you wrote `0..n` so I thought that the xml is wrong. In that case this won't work.

Comment: @PredragMaric yes, a defintiion has 0..n classifications. This is just the cardinality in one way. The other way is also 0..n

Comment: @Hazaart So it's a misunderstanding, it should've been `n..n`. I don't think it's possible then, I'll keep an eye on this thread in case someone else has a jpql solution, I'd be very interested to see it.

Comment: @Hazaart Is native SQL an option for you?

Comment: @PredragMaric Preferably not but perhaps as measure of last resort. This I know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Definition x from the database, do the normal removal process for a Classification and save x again. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is to only use HQL, no altering the object in the JAVA layer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the `orphanRemoval=true` option, so you would only have to delete the `Classiciation` instance from the list of classiciations in the `Definition` instance

Note that this option is only available for 1:n (aka OneToMany) and 1:1 (aka OneToOne) relations, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/)

EDIT:

Since you added the fact that you have a `ManyToMany` relation I would recommend doing something like this:

```
Definition x = fetchSomeDefinitionFromTheDatabase();
Classification c = x.getClassifications().get(0);
x.getClassifications().remove(c);
definitionDaoOrService.update(x);
```

Since you have choosen `save-update` as cascade type, the association between `x` and `c` should be gone, but they both still exist.

Comment: orphanRemoval would delete a Clasification when you eliminate it from a Definition, probably causing an exception if the same Classification is used in another Definition (referential integrity), and it might not be what the OP intended.

Comment: orphanRemoval is only possible in 1:n or 1:1 relations https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/ so the scenario described by you cannot occur